# How can I remove docker compose containers, volumes, networks associated with compose config after it's deleted?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

`sudo docker compose ls --all` output from this shows loads of 'configs' that used to exist but now those files are deleted...

So I can't `docker-compose down -v` without those files... How can I get rid of these configs and their associated resources?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sudo docker system prune` seems to have done the job even though docs here https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/system_prune/ make no mention of `compose`